# How to add checkbox option instead of dropdown for "show entries" in Datatable header

Tags: datatables

I want to remove the dropdown option from "Show entries" portion in Datatable's header. And need to add checkbox for how many rows to shows per page.

https://ibb.co/ngKVLkk

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine some different techniques to implement this:

1. Use the DataTables [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option to customize the table layout.
2. Use a CSS grid layout in combination with the `dom` option, to ensure the page length control is aligned with the search box.
3. Generate the page control HTML dynamically so it can be placed in the HTML generated by the `dom` option.
4. Set an initial page length.
5. Add an event listener to respond to page length changes.
6. Use the DataTables [`.page.len()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.len()) function to actually change the page length.

Here is a demo for the above approach:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: '<"dt-top-container"<"dt-left"><"dt-center"><"dt-right"f>>rtip'
  } );

  var pageLengths = ['5', '20', '50', '100'];

  checkbox_html = pageLengths.map((length, idx) =>  {
    let html = '<input type="radio" class="check-row" name="page_size"';
    if (idx === 0) {
      return html + ' value="' + length + '" checked>' + length;
    } else {
      return html + ' value="' + length + '">' + length;
    }
  }).join(' ');
  $("div.dt-left").html(checkbox_html);

  var intialPageLen = parseInt($('input[name=page_size]:checked', 'body').val());
  table.page.len( intialPageLen ).draw();

  $( 'body' ).on( 'click', 'input[name=page_size]', function() {
    table.page.len( $( this ).val() ).draw();
  });

} );
```

```css
.check-row {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 2px 0 8px;
}

div.dt-top-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

div.dt-left {
}

div.dt-center {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div.dt-right {
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office in Country</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior "Technical" Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Radio Buttons not Check Boxes**

I changed your check boxes to radio buttons, since these ensure that only one value is selected at a time.

**Additional Notes**

Change the page lengths array to whatever you want:

```
var pageLengths = ['5', '20', '50', '100'];
```

The HTML for these page lengths is built using the `pageLengths.map()` logic. The first value in the array is the one which is used for the initial table display.

The `dom` option is used to manage what gets placed in the top left hand field above the Datatable:

```
'<"dt-top-container"<"dt-left"><"dt-center"><"dt-right"f>>rtip'
```

This is where the CSS grid layout is used.

Finally, the click event is where we re-draw the table, to change the page length:

```
table.page.len( $( this ).val() ).draw();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working perfectly in HTML. But, facing a warning on WordPress website like "DataTables warning: table id=example - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3". Thanks again.

Comment: You can try using the [`retrieve`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/retrieve) option (I do not know if that will help, or not), but really it would be better to understand why WordPress is causing this. Sorry, I don't use WordPress, myself. Maybe ask a new, specific WordPress question about this?